# What benefits of math can be conveyed to mid/high schoolers?

Tags: soft-question, teaching

I'm teaching mathematical proof writing to a few of math teachers (in the US) this summer. In the beginning of class, I send a survey asking them why they are here. Most of them are here for getting master degree in teaching to further secure their teaching position. I sense a bit of reluctance, since on the nose mathematical proof writing does not relate too much to teaching mid/high schoolers.

I wish I know how to motivate, but I don't. I was trained formally, and was not aware of some concrete applications of higher math until I taught an applied algebra course last year. It's definitely great to see how group theory is actually used in a nontrivial way to real life problem (coding theory, crypto.. etc).

While my knowledge base was extended a bit from that, it seems to only motivate those who are interested in CS. How about other students? I sincerely believe that there are ways to motivate the not-yet traumatized! Please share your experience on (could-be) successful ways to motivate mid/high schoolers. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Huh, I guess the ability to abstract problems, find logical connections, and come up with solutions is not a useful skill for life...

Comment: This question is better asked at [Math Educators SE](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out @JosephO'Rourke. I wasn't aware of that place, and saw some question about math teaching here..

Comment: What motivates yourself?

Comment: I can't help but mention Lockhart's Lament...although I know this may not really be helpful to you.

Comment: Teach them the most important and widely applicable proof techniques, such as "This result is too beautiful to not be true", "It suffices to show that X is true ... AND IT IS!!", "If you fall asleep, you can get the rest of the proof from someone else. If everyone falls asleep, there is no someone else. And the result is established", "Assume the result is not true ... then without further explanation, pronounce, CONTRADICTION." Also teach them the generalized WLOG operator, which either stand for Without Loss of Generality or With Loss of Generality, so it always applies.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I understand that your comment is meant as a joke, but it is not helpful.